# Subview won't hide correctly in custom UITableViewCell on toggling of UITableView edit

Tags: ios, uitableview

So my app has an editable and sortable UITableView in its left hamburger basement:

[image: Editable UITableView]

To make sure the table cells were skinny enough to show both the delete button and the sorting drag handle on edit, I created a custom UITableViewCell to handle the editing of the table cells:

[image: UITableView on edit]

Everything works fine on edit, but when I tap done, instead of hiding the delete button hangs around:

[image: UITableView on done]

The code for this, inside of BookmarkTableViewCell.m, is:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
  [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];

  if (editing) {
    for (UIView * view in self.subviews) {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
            UIView *movedReorderControl = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))];
            [movedReorderControl addSubview:view];
            [self addSubview:movedReorderControl];
            CGRect newFrame = movedReorderControl.frame;
            newFrame.origin.x = -35;
            movedReorderControl.frame = newFrame;
        }
    }
    UIImageView *deleteBtn = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 24, 24)];
    [deleteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_delete.png"]];
    [self addSubview:deleteBtn];
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need anymore details. Any insight into fixing this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're adding the deleteBtn, but you aren't removing it. if editing is false you should locate the deleteBtn cell and remove it from it's superview so it goes away.

Comment: James, I had tried that in the past, but your bit about "you should locate the deleteBtn" made me realize I might need to be searching harder for it than I was. That led me to trying 'deleteBtn.tag = DELETE_TAG;' and, if editing is false, '[[self viewWithTag:DELETE_TAG] removeFromSuperview];' and that's worked! Thanks a lot.